# "Email - is already registered" error when logging using google

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, email

I can't recall which OpenID provider I used when I registered my account BuZain on stackoverflow sometime back. I've tried all the options and every time I edit my account and put my email address buzain [at] gmail.com it gives the error "Email - is already registered". Is there a way to know which OpenID is associated with my account?

Comment: It would be a bad, from a security standpoint, for them to give you that information.

Comment: There is something... odd with these accounts. I can probably help but I need to confirm identity first.

Comment: thanks to Ian's tip, I emailed team@stackoverflow.com and they told me which OpenID provider i used. I managed to login once and wanted to attach another provider but failed. Now I can't even login with the initial provider.

Comment: Issue resolved by the very helpful guys behind team@stackoverflow.com. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Email team@stackoverflow.com for help on this one