# Careers: Email is already registered

Tags: support, jobs, user-accounts

Yet another question for the "email address is already registered" issue.

I was using a MyOpenID account when it happened. I've just added my Google account (with which the email address is associated) as an OpenID provider, which may make this more complicated.

Comment: [The last time that this was asked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15583/email-is-already-registered-error-when-logging-using-google), it appears that the answer was to send an email to the team. This is an individual issue, really not something that is relevant to everyone or needs to be discussed here.

Comment: I've just sent email, but I was confused because the instructions say that email support is for paying users only, and that Meta is the preferred forum for unpaid support issues. Anyway, I'll try my luck. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. I hadn't realized that the Careers site said that, I don't use it much. It's always OK to post here when you're unsure, of course!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you send an e-mail to careers@stackoverflow.com we can fix that issue for you.

Comment: sackoverflow? :)

Comment: Blah. I'm a terrible typist.

Comment: No harm done, especially here on Meta you can count on the users to fix every typo quickly and efficiently. :)

Comment: By the way, off topic question: as employee of Stack Exchange do you get powers beyond your reputation points e.g. can you now downvote posts here? Just curious, and there's nothing official about it.

Comment: Nope. I have to earn rep here just like everyone else.

Comment: Hmm... I'm almost sure I once saw diamondless user retag with moderator only tag (e.g. [meta-tag:status-completed]) and turned out he was employee, so guess the devs grant the privileges per demand or something. :)